# Windows 7 shows "Network Cable Unpugged" If connected through IO port

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection, switch

I am facing a strange problem while connecting a new windows 7 machine (will be referred as machine A) to a dell switch. Here are few points to better understand my problem:

> 1. When machine A is connected directly to a switch port(lets say port 10), it gets connected.(gets IP Address from DHCP).
> 2. When the same machine is connected through IO port(internal cabling as in offices), it displays "Network Cable is Unplugged" displaying a cross sign over connection icon in system tray.
> 3. When any another machine(Vista or 7) is connected through this IO port, it gets connected instantly.
> 4. When any other machine is directly connected to port 10 it works.
> 5. When machine A is connected to any other port(I tried 5 different ports) using IO ports, it does not work.

The switch works in MAC binded configuration(Static Address) and I am sure that I'm not making any mistakes in configuring the correct port on the switch for the system's MAC.
Also I tried re installing Ethernet drivers, disabling-enabling, restarting system nearly 14-15 times but none worked. Please suggest any possible solution. Also feel free to ask if any confusion is there in the above literature.

> Update: 
>   The internal cabling of IO port has been totally renewed. Also because Dell machine was in warranty, we  asked them to check and they replaced the motherboard after some diagnosis.

Comment: Do you still have the issue after the Motherboard replacement, and are all the machines of the same make (motherboard,NIC,drivers,etc) ?

Comment: Yes, motherboard replacement did not resolve the problem. There were total 6 machines brought of the same make model from dell and 2 of them are having this problem. Other 4 are working flawless. To make my question simple I didn't wrote all this.